# Why does a copy and paste of a JPEG image create a dot files folder?

Tags: windows-vista, images

When I copy a JPG image from any source and paste it to any destination on my computer, a hidden folder automatically appears next to that image with the same name followed by "dot files".

Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

I'm using a Sony Vaio with Windows Vista.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Vaio has a content analyzer which is toying with the images as they're pasted in.

Found this solution at [Microsoft Answers](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistamedia/thread/89a50671-eca9-4fd5-9c63-1d68eff17e32):

> Problem is with vaio content analyzer software that comes along with vaio.
>
> Just search for the Vaio content analyzer (settings) and unmark
>
> - video analysis
> - picture analysis
> - music analysis

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's some copy handler installed either by a virus or by some explorer extension...